# SQL Server Security Logins

Tags: sql, security

On our Development and test servers I have added a windows authentication login for a new employee.  I need this login to work for all databases on the server and to allow for them to be able to create, add, etc.  I know if I set the server role to sysadmin it will allow all the permissions but is this the proper way to set up the user?  Should there be some other role that I should map the user to and grant permissions through that role?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "etc."?

Comment: Depends on what those users need to do. If they need to be admin, it's fine. If you want to restrict what they can do, you can grant them the least privilege they need. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669084(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Just looked up the different rolls and I think what I am looking for would be to set the user up as the DbCreator role.  Don't want them to be full admin but I think DbCreator role would work for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not good idea,for a couple of reasons.For example the user can execute windows shell commands through this permission and get access of you servers

---

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'shutdown -s';

---

Also it helps to hackers to get control of your servers via sql injection and other hacking methods...